# Setting my button's position programmatically in swift

Tags: swift

I've been using auto layout so far, so I'm not sure how this works.

I have a simple button I want to be close to my down right corner. 
How can its position programmatically in swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

view.addSubview(button)

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).active = true
button.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).active = true
```

Setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` is necessary. By default, the property is set to `true` for any view you *programmatically* create.

In this case you need only 2 constraints (`bottomAnchor` and `trailingAnchor`). Since the button has the `intrinsicContentSize` (the natural size based on the title and stuff), you don't have to add constraints for the height/width.

Also you might want to use the `layoutMarginsGuide` to pin the button to the edges of the superview. This way you don't need to specify the constants:

```
superView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)

let margins = superView.layoutMarginsGuide

button.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.bottomAnchor).active = true
button.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

Note that if the view is a view controller’s *root view*, then the system sets and manages the margins. The top and bottom margins are set to 0 points. The side margins vary depending on the current size class, but can be either 16 or 20 points. You *cannot* change these margins.

Comment: I tried this and wasn't seeing the button until I changed it to `let button = UIButton(type: .System)`.

Comment: Probably because you haven't set background color for the button. So it was white on white

Comment: Yep.  Setting the background color made it appear.

Answer (score -2):

You can use autolayout programmatically.

[SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) is a nice swift library to make the autolayour code more easy to use and readable.

Otherwise you can always use it the normal way. These are two nice tutorials on it:

[1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)
[2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints)